# Is it a sin to hide a halal marriage, denying it in public?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

I have been secretly married to a man for a year now. We cannot disclose our marriage because the parents of my husband would not approve of it.

Is it a sin to hide the nikkah and deny it in public yet live like husband and wife in private?

Isn't it sinful to keep the nikkah secret since construct of family is not possible with a discreet nikkah?